# FileCodeModel::AddFunction generates a function with return type when passed vsCMFunctionConstructor

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, c#-code-model

**This piece of code is what i want to generate (c++)**

```
X::X()
{
}
```

However, the [AddFunction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms168313.aspx) call bellow generates a function **with return type** (source being a FileCodeModel representing a cpp source file):

```
source.AddFunction("X::X" , vsCMFunction.vsCMFunctionConstructor, null, -1,vsCMAccess.vsCMAccessDefault);
```

Replacing the null with any of these return types make no difference:

"X"

[vsCMTypeRef](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.vscmtyperef%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).vsCMTypeRefVoid

[vsCMTypeRef](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.vscmtyperef%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).vsCMTypeRefCodeType

[vsCMTypeRef](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.vscmtyperef%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).vsCMTypeRefOther

All of these results in a function with return type like below, even tough vsCMFunctionConstructor is specified:

```
int X::X()
{
}
```

Using the FileCodeModel interface, how can i generate a simple constructor, that is a function **without** return type?

*[Here is the most minimal code to recreate my problem](http://pastebin.com/fUFiV45H).*

Comment: What language are you generating? It looks like C++. FWIW generating a C# constructor this way works fine for me.

Comment: Yes c++. Didnt think it would matter since constructor code looks exactly the same. That is interesting however and should help me pin down the problem.

Comment: Ok, then can you post a little more code, just enough so we can recreate your problem?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/fUFiV45H
And a complete vs sample project:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/smnvwej6quysegb/tXRFTNbCwv

Comment: @ David Kron Shouldn't you add a constructor to the class object that you got via AddClass function? like they do here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/x6h10s6x(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @o_weisman The problem with that is that the implementation gets generated in the same file as where the class where declared, ie the header and not the source file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, looking at your sample project, I think I can see the problem.

You have opened a `FileCodeModel` on a .cpp file and you are adding a function to it - but there's no class.

Also, for generating C++, you should make sure you use [`VCCodeModel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.vccodemodel.vccodemodel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

What you should do is to create a class first, then add the constructor to the class. Something like this:

```
// get IDE
EnvDTE.DTE dte = (EnvDTE.DTE)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.12.0");

// select the second project (pre-created as in your example)
var project = dte.Solution.Projects.Item(2);

// get the VC code model
VCCodeModel pModel = (VCCodeModel)project.CodeModel;

// create a class in the header (also creates header if not existing)
var pClass = pModel.AddClass("X", "test.h");

// add the constructor implementation in the cpp file 
pClass.AddFunction("X", EnvDTE.vsCMFunction.vsCMFunctionConstructor, null, 
       0, EnvDTE.vsCMAccess.vsCMAccessDefault, "test.cpp");
```

This correctly generates the following code in the `test.h` file:

```
class X
{
    X(void);
};
```

And the following `test.cpp` file:

```
#include "test.h"

X::X(void)
{
}
```

Comment: You usually don't define classes in the cpp file, only their member functions.

Comment: This ^, seem to be my real problem, i create the class in the header file but i want to add the implementation in a relative source file. I somehow need to tell the VCCodeModel what source file the class object should be linked to as-well. But i see now how my example where to simple. You have however still answered my original question and i will most likely select this answer soon.

Comment: @DavidKron Understood - see amended answer for a complete solution that creates the necessary header and cpp file for you.

Comment: THANK YOU. I owe you for life! It even added the include statement! Take the rep! (Oh, in 11h that is..)